# Hi-res web-based graphing

Tags: library, javascript, graphs

I am looking for a way to build web-based dashboard graphs that allow for details.

I've explored the usual jQuery libs like Flot, jqplot, morris, and so forth, and while they are all pretty, they simply do not offer the resolution I need for certain graphs.

For example, we want to monitor file movements of our system for a day to show when we were laggard.  Every 5 seconds there is a data point.  Do the math and over an 8-hour workday, they're a lot of pixels to draw.

Most libs will group or cut, which may ruin the hit points we care about most.  In a 500 px wide div, with 5000+ points, you can't fit 10 points on 1 pixel.

What's the solution?

For now, we're using Excel, as it's the only tool we've found capable of graphing in this manner accounting for the high points and grouping more average points.  We care more about outliers.   But this is also a manual process and sent by email after the fact.  We have a dashboard framework in place and data available in JSON format, we just need a viewer for it.  Theses need to be dynamic as possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Writing your own simple script that creates SVGs would be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Chart for JavaScript](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/chart/line) can plot all the 5760 points in your example and allow you to scroll through them. Simple sample application:[link](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/fbf5f1wm).

The whole suite of controls is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Looks like a very nice suite with good graphing.  Unfortunately, I'm commercial and do have options to pursue non mit-/gpl licenses at this time.

Comment: @briansol Essential Studio for JS [commercial](http://www.syncfusion.com/sales/products/javascript). I only mentioned the community license option as more people are interested in the free version.

Comment: Which many of us are - yay!  :-)